# Endless scroll issue tumblr, posts at bottom of page "stack"

Tags: post, scroll, tumblr, infinite, stacked

Here's the issue: tumblr theme that I am using is the NTA 3 column option found on this page (http://themes.ville-noire.com/), which says that I should have 3 columns, infinite scrolling and be able to use a banner. But the earlier posts at the bottom of the page on my blog (http://incandescending.tumblr.com/) do not infinite scroll, and instead kind of stack up, blocking each other.

Do you have any suggestions for why this might be happening and what I can try to fix it? I'm trying to learn and understand a little bit of how coding works but my knowledge/research/attempts haven't done the trick so far- any help appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the behaviour you are seeing?

Comment: In the future, please provide code rather than just a link because I had to hunt for your script calls. I don't know how much it matters, but your callback to `masonry` in the `infinitescroll` call isn't properly formatted. It should be: `function( newElements ) { var $newElems = $( newElements ); $('.posts').masonry( 'appended', $newElems ); }`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the posts don't have a specific height set so the reason they're 'stacking up' and blocking each other at first is because the height of each post is not defined until they're finished loading.